# Svelte: two way binding triggers reactivity twice

Tags: javascript, svelte-3

Does someone know why if i bind a property to a component it triggers reactivity twice?
I created a REPL to recreate the problem.

https://svelte.dev/repl/71c60ba3ff5f429284472c5b0e0a6c0e?version=3.32.3

Thanks

Comment: Did you find an answer to this behavior?

Comment: [Fred Hors](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10088259) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68577839) saying "I opened [https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/6590](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/6590) to better understand this behaviour."

Answer (score -1):

Maybe without `bind` would work?
https://svelte.dev/repl/20b6ee11a69b49408928b35d3fd95041?version=3.32.3

Comment: of course, but this way i would need to trigger an event to warn the parent component that the object changed. That was not what I wanted.

Comment: if i have a tree of components, and i change the object in the last component of the tree, I would need to trigger an event in each layer of the tree to get the parent notified about the change. i don't think that this is a good solution.

Comment: @RuiMartins try to use writable store, https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores

Comment: @RuiMartins .subscribe() method will emit the updated value only once

Comment: Let's say that i have a page with a filter component, inside this filter I have several input components (text inputs, sliders, etc). Then in the store I have a writable filter property, in the same store, I have kind of a watcher that triggers a call to backend to retrieve some data according to that filter.

Comment: My goal is to subscribe to that filter in the page and then pass this filter property as a two-way binding prop into the filter component, and then into it's childs. This will trigger some updates in the store event without the property has changed, do you understand?